# Suspended in index rebuild

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012, an Index Rebuild job is taking a very long time (up to 8 hours). However, not even one Index rebuild completed, so I stopped the index job.

In monitoring SQL task:

```
state = SUSPENDED
, comment = ALTER INDEX
, APPLICATION name = Microsoft SQL server Management Studio
, Query Wait = LCK_M_SCH_M 
, Head Blocker = object lock 
lock Partition = 15 
objid=585105175 
subresource=FULL 
dbid=5 
id=lockaa7aae200 
mode=Sch-S 
associatedObjectId=585105175 1386
```

Thanks in advance for any helpful info.

Comment: `LCK_M_SCH_M` means something has a schema lock that is blocking your process.  If you run `sp_who2`, you should see a blocking process that is preventing the index rebuild from proceeding.

Comment: @amin: Any news for this? have you seen the comment and the answers?

Answer (score 8):

The reason that your index rebuild isn't completing is because of the `LCK_M_SCH_M` wait type.  What happens when you try to rebuild an index, a `Sch-M` lock is requested on the object that you're trying to rebuild.

Please see this below [chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186396%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) for **lock compatibility**:

[image]

As you can see here, a `Sch-M` lock has a conflict with almost every locking scenario (shared, exclusive, update, schema stability, etc.).

Here's a small example showing what may be happening in your environment.  To create the test object in a test database:

```
use TestDB;
go

create table dbo.ConcurrencyTest
(
    id int identity(1, 1) not null
        constraint PK_ConcurrencyTest_Id primary key clustered,
    some_int int not null
        default 1
);
go

insert into dbo.ConcurrencyTest
default values;
go 100
```

Now if one session is executing a query, and it keeps the lock open (I'm using an update query and not committing the transaction):

```
use TestDB;
go

begin tran;

    update dbo.ConcurrencyTest
    set some_int = 2
    where id = 7;

--commit tran;
```

And if another session attempts to rebuild the clustered index on that table:

```
use TestDB;
go

alter index PK_ConcurrencyTest_Id
on dbo.ConcurrencyTest
rebuild;
go
```

It's going to be blocked by the initial `UPDATE` query.  We can see this through a little diagnostic query below:

```
select
    l.resource_type,
    l.resource_associated_entity_id,
    l.request_mode,
    l.request_status,
    l.request_session_id,
    st.text as blocked_sql_text,
    r.blocking_session_id,
    stb.text as blocking_sql_text
from sys.dm_tran_locks l
inner join sys.dm_exec_connections c
on l.request_session_id = c.session_id
left join sys.dm_exec_requests r
on l.request_session_id = r.session_id
inner join sys.dm_exec_connections cb
on r.blocking_session_id = cb.session_id
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(c.most_recent_sql_handle) st
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cb.most_recent_sql_handle) stb
where l.resource_database_id = db_id('TestDB')
and l.request_status = 'WAIT'
and r.blocking_session_id is not null
and r.blocking_session_id > 0;
```

My output looks like the following:

[image]

As you can see here, my `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` command is being blocked by the `UPDATE` query.  The request lock is the `Sch-M` lock that is required on the `OBJECT` in order for this operation to complete.

Due to this concurrency conflict, it is advisable to schedule your index maintenance (as well as other maintenance tasks) during a window where there is little to no user load.

Comment: This is a good answer and a great example! +1

Comment: I know this is so old but I am stuck with an Alter Index Rebuild like this. I have had an Alter Index Rebuild running for 6+ hours. and the status of the Alter Index process is “suspended”. It also has a wait type of LCK_M_SCH_M and it appears there are 100 or so other processes being blocked by the SPID of the Rebuild. Is there a way to abort the Rebuild or will it eventually finish? I cant tell if its even doing anything. by the way  the database is ~40GB.

Answer (score 0):

We typically time our larger index maintenance operations to take place in midnight when there's minimal business-use. Without knowing the business-critical constraints on the task, you might want to force the database into single_user mode in case there are too many non-critical queries being run against the database during the maintenance period. Assuming this won't cause other problems of course, depends on the system as a whole.